# Comma separated string to symbols

Tags: ruby

Do you know any elegant way to achieve this in ruby plz ?

```
 string = 'title,url'
 #expected final variable => :title,:url or 'title','url'
```

I've looked in the API documentation (both ruby and rails) and didn't find any simple method, before writing any loop I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.

Thx !

Comment: Do you want the result as an array?

Comment: Yep I think it would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string.split(",").map &:to_sym # => [:title, :url]
```

Comment: So, there are not methods on an array or hash to convert keys to symbols ?

Comment: The `map` method is the appropriate way to do this. My solution first splits the string into an array of strings, then converts those to symbols.

Comment: Yes, I understand what your function is doing. Thx for your help.